# C++ Printing Array

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

So I have a 2d array I'm using as a gridmap where each array block is a space on a map.

So in my main() I've initialized array 'Map' with

```
char Map[ROWS][COLS]={'x'};
```

ROWS = 10 and COLS = 20

Later I call function PrintMap with

```
void PrintMap(const char Map[ROWS][COLS], const bool showTreasure)
{


for (int countr=0; countr<ROWS;countr++){
    for (int countc=0; countc<COLS;countc++){      //print map
            if (!showTreasure){
                    if (Map[countr][countc]!='T')
                            cout << Map[countr][countc];
                    else
                            cout << '*';
            } else {

                    cout << Map[countr][countc];

            }
    }
cout << endl;
}



}
```

One space on the grid is where the treasure or goal in the game is located. In the parameters for PrintMap is bool showTreasure which is whether or not you want a 'T' to be shown on the map or if you want to hide it.

So one of the spaces in the array will be a 'T' while all the others will be either '*', 'X', or 'P'.

The * is where nothing is located.

So the if statements are supposed to say: If showTreasure is false (meaning you want to hide the 'T'): you print what is in the array if it's not a 'T' or print an '*' if it is a T.

Now my problem is that even I've initialized the array with 200 *s, when I run the program it only prints out 1 *.

Comment: Well, it would help if you showed the initialization code you speak of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initialization is this line:

```
char Map[ROWS][COLS]={'x'};
```

Then the matrix is initialized to a single `x` followed by 199 NULL characters.

See the excellent explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/29157.

For more about `std::fill()` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3948314/29157

Thanks for the tip, [CantChooseUsernames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462718/cantchooseusernames)!

Comment: Oh I thought that was supposed to fill all characters with that. What is the syntax for that then?

Comment: Use `std::fill(&Map[0][0], &Map[Rows][Cols], 'X');`  from `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Nevermind. I see the answer in the link.